# Java-Generics & WildCard Code Explanation

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I was studying Generics & Wildcard usage using some samples and I could not understand following code:

```
 public static <W extends Enum<?>> Enum<?> getType(Class<W> returnType){ return;}
```

Also, is this a correct way to extend? (say `FruitType` and `VeggieType` is Enum class..):

```
 public static <W extends fruitType & veggieType> Enum<?> getType Class<W> returnType)
```

Comment: What don't you understand exactly ? I was writing an answer when I realized I was just reformulating the line of code, what anyone can do

Comment: All Enum <?>  part.. and why Class parameter needs <W>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <W extends Enum<?>> Enum<?> getType(Class<W> returnType){ return;}
```

means you are declaring a static method returning an `Enum`. This method takes as a parameter a `Class<W>` instance where W is a class which derives from `Enum`. `Enum` is a raw-type, but here you are unable to tell which class will be used to parametrize it, here comes the `<?>`, which is probably equivalent to `<Object>` or *nothing*.

`Class` is also a raw-type, for example `String.class` returns an instance of type `Class<String>`.

Your last snippet compiles (after the edit) and means that rather than being an `Enum` like in the first snippet, `W` has to be a subtype of `FruitType` and `VeggieType`.

Comment: Thanks for response. So if I know what class will be used to parameterize, which are fruitType and veggieType, then should I write the statement as   'public static <W extends fruitType & veggieType>' not like the second snippet?

Comment: Edit your question if you want, all I know is that the second snippet does not compile (although I cannot say exactly why).